# slick reusable InsertAndUpdate trait

Tags: scala, slick

In the light of DRY, I'm trying to avoid the duplication of insert and update logic in Slick table definitions. I tried this:

```
trait Entity {
    def id: Option[Int]
}

case class BankRekening(id: Option[Int], nummer: String, omschrijving: String) extends Entity{
}

object BankRekeningen extends Table[BankRekening]("bankrekening") with InsertAndUpdate[BankRekening] {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def nummer = column[String]("nummer")
    def omschrijving = column[String]("omschrijving")
    def * = id.? ~ nummer ~ omschrijving <> (BankRekening, BankRekening.unapply _)
    def idx_nummer = index("idx_nummer", nummer, unique = true)
}

trait InsertAndUpdate[T <: Entity] {
    this: Table[T] =>

    def id: scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int]

    def insert(obj: T): T = {
        obj.copy(id = Some(this.returning(this.id) insert obj))
    }
}
```

Now the compiler complains about 'obj' in the last statement, saying: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[T]

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a hunch, but have you imported `scala.slick.driver.<yourdbdriver>.simple._`?

Comment: waffle paradox, yes he has which is the intermediate cause of the "problem" (the ultimate one being Scalac producing a misleading error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer: You try to call copy on T, which does not have a copy method.

The long answer: Unfortunately, Scalac, the Scala compiler let's Slick (unintendedly) high-jack the error message. You should have seen an error `value copy is not a member of T`. In case of `copy` Scalac somehow swallows that message because of the implicits Slick puts in scope. Here is a reduced reproduction:

```
object simple{
    implicit def intColumnType: TypedType[Int] = null
    implicit def valueToConstColumn[T : TypedType](v: T) = ConstColumn(v)
}
import simple._
trait TypedType[T]
case class ConstColumn[T](v: T){
  def bar = 5
}

trait InsertAndUpdate[T] {
    def insert(obj: T): T = {
      5.copy() // <- unexpected, but is valid and compiles fine
      5.bar    // compiles fine

      obj.bar    // error: value bar is not a member of type parameter T
                 // error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type TypedType[T]

      obj.copy() // error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type TypedType[T]
    }
}
```

As you can see the message is somehow swallowed for `copy`. Also I do not find the message `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type TypedType[T]` helpful. I created a Scala ticket to fix this: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7907

Comment: I now see that Entity is not a case class but a trait. Had a case class in mind, therefore expected to have the copy method. 5.copy compiles because 5 'is a case class'...?

Comment: You cannot inherit from case classes, thus Entity could not be a case class. 5 is not a case class. 5.copy() works because ConstColumn is a case class and the compiler applies valueToConstColumn to convert 5 into something that has a copy method. valueToConstColumn is applicable for Int because there is an implicit TypedType[Int] in scope. But in case of the copy method this conversion was probably not intended by the user. Maybe we should change ConstColumn to an ordinary class in Slick to avoid this.